# What does the kernel do once put into memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I'm a first year grad student trying to write an Operating System from scratch as a side project. I've read the Linux Programming Interface, Modern Operating Systems 4th edition, a bunch of articles on OSdev wiki's, and anything I can find on Google, but I'm having a tough time finding what I should be doing next after writing a simple bootloader, and a kernel that can take user input and display it back onto the screen.

I have a feeling that I need to create some drivers that interact with the file system and memory, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm trying to work my way up with just physical memory and one process running "kernel" for right now. I'll worry about virtual memory (pagging) and multi-processes later. If anyone can give me some kind of direction or better understanding of what happens when the kernel is finally put into memory, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not suitable for "give me directions" questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point a resource that will be of great help for you to understand this stuff in real details. One of the great and evolving resource that is being maintained on git.

https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/tree/master/Booting

Comment: Thank you so much! I can’t wait to dig into this.

Comment: I hope it solved your issue, if so you can mark the question solved. @AaronV77